# Joomla vs Drupal vs Ваш вариант - на чем можно быстро сделать высоконагруженный проект

Tags: drupal, joomla, php, wordpress, html5

Те кто использовал эти движки напишите в чем их отличии, я привык использовать шаблон mvc, может какие то из них используют шаблоны и что то более понятное чем простыни говнокода.

А теперь вообще что мне нужно сделать.

Из за нехватки времени нужно быстренько запустить проект, ну допустим за неделю за 2.

На сайте должны регистрироваться все желающие, у каждого пользователя должна быть своя страница доступная из поиска и из главной страницы.

Страничка юзеров чем то будет похожа на вконтакте по структуре но естественно никакого видео и музыки, просто и ничего лишнего.

Только возможность грузить фотки если потребуется.

Так же у каждого пользователя будет карта от гугла где он сможет ставить метки и другие участники смогут смотреть эти метки.

Ну и админка естественно будет, но пока думаю будет одна без модераторов.

Еще главное условие, сайт должен работать на планшетах и смартфонах, это основной трафик сайта.

Еще важно то что дизайн я хочу купить готовый и качественный, но мне нужно понять как все упростить с точки зрения разработки  и самое главное на чем его писать

Со временем проект может стать высоко нагруженным, сейчас сразу планируется 300 посетителей с глубиной просмотра 50 страниц.

В общем я пока не могу решить, писать свой движок или быстрее будет допустим быстрее готовый дизайн куда нибудь прикрутить.

Те кто дочитал, подумайте, - а за сколько бы времени вы смогли бы реализовать такой проект и главное на чем стали его делать?

главное не ошибиться, чтобы потом не было проблем с доработкой

забыл написать, что основная фишка будет быстрый поиск по сайту, в общем нужно о нем тоже как то подумать

проект явно требует очень много мозгов...

Comment: попробуйте [express](http://expressjs.com/) на nodejs , вот [примеры пользователей](http://expressjs.com/applications.html)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте друпал. Он вполне с легкостью справится с вашей задачей, особенно, с поиском.
Надо признать, что обе CMSки довольно тяжелые по числу запросов, но здесь окупится временем разворачивания: чуть позже подключите memcache, а впоследствии, если будет желание, напишете свою на одном из фреймворков.

UPD: за неделю вполне можно управиться, если не фелонить. Еще одна на тесты.

Comment: у друпала как я слышал сложности с освоением и нет понятной ооп структуры и шаблонов проектирования или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: зачем ему CMS вообще ?

Comment: >сложности с освоением 

Сложностей немного. В основном - изучить термины.

>нет понятной ооп структуры 
 
В 7 уже имеется.

>зачем ему CMS вообще?

Затем что с нуля запилить сайт по фреймворку с изучением несколько дольше, чем с цмской, в которой все запрошенные функции уже есть.

Comment: так как раз его запросы не относятся к cms, открытых движков соцсетей вроде кроме полудохлой диаспоры никаких нет. (может и есть, что-то нагуглилось) https://github.com/anahitasocial/anahita вот это на первый взгляд выглядит прилично